# ValueError in Python 3 code

Tags: python, csv

I have this code that will allow me to count the number of missing rows of numbers within the csv for a script in Python 3.6. However, these are the following errors in the program:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\GapReport.py", line 14, in <module>
    EndDoc_Padded, EndDoc_Padded = (int(s.strip()[2:]) for s in line)
  File "C:\Users\GapReport.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    EndDoc_Padded, EndDoc_Padded = (int(s.strip()[2:]) for s in line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AC-SEC 000000001'
```

Code:

```
import csv

def out(*args): 
    print('{},{}'.format(*(str(i).rjust(4, "0") for i in args)))

prev = 0
data = csv.reader(open('Padded Numbers_export.csv'))

print(*next(data), sep=', ') #  header

for line in data:
    EndDoc_Padded, EndDoc_Padded = (int(s.strip()[2:]) for s in line)

if start != prev+1:
    out(prev+1, start-1)

prev = end
    out(start, end)
```

I'm stumped on how to fix these issues.Also, I think the csv many lines in it, so if there's a section that limits it to a few numbers, please feel free to update me on so.

CSV Snippet (Sorry if I wasn't clear before!):

[image: CSV Snippet]

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't convert 'AC-SEC 000000001' to an integer. This makes sense. However, we can't see an example of the CSV so we're unable to help fix it.

Comment: I edited a picture of the csv recently. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is just a guess, but based on the example it looks like you might want something like `EndDoc_Padded1, EndDoc_Padded2 = (int(s.split()[1]) for s in line)`?

Comment: That won't work, as `for s in line` is going to iterate over each character in `line`.

Answer (score 0):

The values you have in your CSV file are not numeric.

For example, `FMAC-SEC 000000001` is not a number. So when you run `int(s.strip()[2:])`, it is not able to convert it to an `int`.

Some more comments on the code:

1. What is the utility of doing `EndDoc_Padded, EndDoc_Padded = (...)`? Currently you are assigning values to two variables with the same name. Either name one of them something else, or just have one variable there.
2. Are you trying to get the two different values from each column? In that case, you need to split `line` into two first. Are the contents of your file comma separated? If yes, then do `for s in line.split(',')`, otherwise use the appropriate separator value in `split()`.
3. You are running this inside a loop, so each time the values of the two variables would get updated to the values from the last line. If you're trying to obtain 2 lists of all the values, then this won't work.

Comment: Thank you! For is listed as syntax error now at the moment.

Comment: Stupid me, it's supposed to be     Control Number_Padded and 
    EndDoc_Padded.

Comment: See my edited answer and make the corrections in your question.